# Can I restrict the Jasper PDF from edited by third party software like Adobe

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have created the Jasper report as PDF with Jaspersoft studio. I need to restrict the user editing the downloaded PDF using any software (Adobe).
Is it possible?
User should be able to see the content in the document but shouldn't be  editing.

Comment: You can use `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.permissions.allowed" value="..."/>` like described at duplicated post

Comment: When I open the downloaded file with above property,it is saying the file is damaged. I want to download the pdf and open to see the content. But when we try to edit through Adobe , it should restrict.